# Create date-dependant function in Flash - possibly with INTERNAL php

Tags: php, flash, date, actionscript-2

So here goes my stackoverflow debut... (And I tried searching and reading thru a lot of posts (php flash date) before asking this)

I would like to make an swf that will find out what date it is and do sometinhg correspondingly. Eg. go to a specific frame or load a movieClip.

I would also like to avoid the Actionscript "Date Class" because I need to feel fairly certain that my end user will see the swf of the day not of his/her local date-setting.

So I'm thinking to somehow bring in php with 'echo date' inside the swf and then have the result create a goto-(or load-)command.

To make matters worse I have to rely only on code within the swf using ActionScript2 (in CS4 or 5). I am not able to publish any outside php (or any other code for that matter) so everything must be done internally. Only swf has to work regardless of server (I am expecting the server will work with php)

**So I hope some gurus here will be able to tell me:
1. If this is possible
2. How I make the date thing happen in Flash
3. And how I somehow grab the date as a variable  (?) and make that determine some action.**

How do you like them apples?

Comment: This would be overwhelmingly easy by making a request to a separate PHP file that returns the current date: `<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>` Are you sure you can't use any outside PHP? Why?

Comment: Yes, I know. And now I am wondering if I may be able to do that anyway. But then I'd have to have that PHP-file on a server that I control - the swf is going to someone elses server - possibly more than one. But I do have my own domain so that could work. But let's suppose I have a date.php on www.mydomain.com/date.php then how do I grab the date-information and use it to control gotoFrame/load. And I must say I feel a potential risk in the case I quit or loose my domain. So I'd still prefer the option to be independant of external php.... But rather a solution that works :-)

Comment: Right then. I've come this far:
Now I have a date.php on my server. And I know how to import and _print_ it to Flash `loadVariablesNum("date.php", 0);` **but I do not know how I can use this variable to control some selection (either frame/mc)**?

Comment: I can't help you with that part, as my last puny dabblings with Flash were six years ago :) But I assume somebody will be able to tell that. Maybe edit your question to reflect the new information, and to bump it back to the top.

Answer (score 0):

To get the date from server, use loadVariablesNum.
Let's say you have the date as string in the format you specified on date.php, "Y-m-d", you can do something like:

```
// split the string into of an array of day, month and year.
var dateString:String = "2011-05-08";
var parts:Array = dateString.split("-");
// now create the date as an Date instance. ( just to be more organized, but you can just save day, month and year into separate vars.
var date:Date = new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2]);
// If you have a frame for each day
gotoAndStop(mydate.getDate());
```

Comment: **Seems freaking awesome :-)**... I won't be able to test this within the next 10 hours - BUT THEN!... Looking forward to trying this.

Comment: **I can't get this working. So I was a little too excited 23 hours ago**. I am not able to understand it correctly, I'm affraid.

But now I do have a set-up where I'm just calling the date (2 diggits, 01-31) and I was able to get it in as a variable and have that inserted into an `attachMovie`.

My problems as of now - I am having trouble getting the variable loading before playhead runs thru everything (this is what I think is going on).
And I need to figure out a back-up for when I (someday) don't have material for the specific date. Perhaps new questions for those.